# Transaction Error JTA DATASOURCE JPA CDI

Tags: jpa, cdi, jta

data-source with JBoss EAP in my project.

For some reason when i try to persist an object i get the error below.

> JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either
>   use a transaction or extended persistence context):
>   javax.faces.FacesException: #{back.salvar}:
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469:
>   Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a
>   transaction or extended persistence context)

There is @Transactional method but this method launch the error.
Anyone?

```
@Stateless
@Named
public class BaseDao implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8993128837557701804L;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager manager;

    @Transactional
    public void persist(Object object)
    {
        manager.persist(object);
    }

}
```

PS: All objects are injected with CDI, the manager is injected with the object class org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager

Comment: Can you please include your `persistence.xml` and the implementation of `#{back.salver}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your CDI bean is an EJB stateless session bean, you don't have to use `@Transactional` annotation here since EJB have Container Managed Transaction (CMT) by default.

`@Transactional` is useful to manage transaction transaction on a CDI managed bean (i.e. POJO).